# how to sum up specific cells of a column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame named **BalticRainfallDuration**. A small portion of the data frame is shown below.

```
    "TIMESTAMP"     "Rainfall"  "Duration"
2014-03-19 10:40:00     0.508   0
2014-03-19 10:50:00     1.016   10
2014-03-19 11:00:00     0.254   10
2014-03-24 09:10:00     0.254   7090
2014-03-26 12:40:00     0.254   3090
2014-03-27 11:50:00     0.254   1390
2014-03-27 12:20:00     0.254   30
2014-03-28 14:30:00     0.254   1570
2014-03-28 14:40:00     0.508   10
2014-03-28 14:50:00     0.508   10
2014-03-28 15:00:00     0.254   10
2014-03-28 15:10:00     0.508   10
2014-03-28 15:20:00     0.254   10
2014-03-28 15:40:00     0.254   20
2014-03-29 13:00:00     0.254   1280
```

For each events of continuous 10 mins rainfall present in the TIMESTAMP, I want to sum up the "Duration" for those corresponding events. The output dataframe **"Event_Duration"** should be as follows:

```
"TIMESTAMP"        "Rainfall"     "Duration"  "Duration_sum"
2014-03-19 10:40:00     0.508             0      
2014-03-19 10:50:00     1.016            10         20         
2014-03-19 11:00:00     0.254            10
2014-03-24 09:10:00     0.254          7090         NA
2014-03-26 12:40:00     0.254          3090         NA
2014-03-27 11:50:00     0.254          1390         NA
2014-03-27 12:20:00     0.254            30         NA
2014-03-28 14:30:00     0.254          1570         NA
2014-03-28 14:40:00     0.508            10     
2014-03-28 14:50:00     0.508            10    
2014-03-28 15:00:00     0.254            10         50
2014-03-28 15:10:00     0.508            10     
2014-03-28 15:20:00     0.254            10
2014-03-28 15:40:00     0.254            20         NA
2014-03-29 13:00:00     0.254          1280         NA
```

which means that there were 2 continuous 10 mins duration rainfall events. Event 1 is 20 mins and event 2 is 50 mins.

I tried the following code:

```
Event_Duration<-with(BalticRainfallDuraiton,diff(BalticRainfallDuraiton$TIMESTAMP)==10, sum(BalticRainfallDuraiton$Duration))

Duration_Sum<-data.frame(cbind(BalticRainfallDuration,Event_Duration))
```

But in the output I am only receiving TRUE or FALSE results rather than the values of duration sums.
I will highly appreciate if someone can help me out by suggesting corrections to my code or provide an alternative code.

Comment: the '20' and '50' should be 1 row below right in the ata?

Comment: the position of 20 and 50 does not matter, as long as these are the cumulative sum of duration for each rainfall event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
library( dplyr )
df <- df %>%
    mutate( grp = ifelse( Duration > 10, 1, 0 ) ) %>%
    mutate( grp = cumsum( grp ) ) %>%
    group_by( grp ) %>%
    mutate( Duration_sum = c( rep( NA, n() - 1 ), sum( Duration ) - Duration[1] ) ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate( grp = NULL )
```

Which gives:

```
> df
# A tibble: 15 × 4
             TIMESTAMP Rainfall Duration Duration_sum
                <dttm>    <dbl>    <int>        <int>
1  2014-03-19 10:40:00    0.508        0           NA
2  2014-03-19 10:50:00    1.016       10           NA
3  2014-03-19 11:00:00    0.254       10           20
4  2014-03-24 09:10:00    0.254     7090            0
5  2014-03-26 12:40:00    0.254     3090            0
6  2014-03-27 11:50:00    0.254     1390            0
7  2014-03-27 12:20:00    0.254       30            0
8  2014-03-28 14:30:00    0.254     1570           NA
9  2014-03-28 14:40:00    0.508       10           NA
10 2014-03-28 14:50:00    0.508       10           NA
11 2014-03-28 15:00:00    0.254       10           NA
12 2014-03-28 15:10:00    0.508       10           NA
13 2014-03-28 15:20:00    0.254       10           50
14 2014-03-28 15:40:00    0.254       20            0
15 2014-03-29 13:00:00    0.254     1280            0
```

A few steps in here might not be necessary,  depending on specifically how you want the output to look like. Likewise, you may want to get rid of the zero duration values (just an extra `mutate` step at the end).